# how to save values in the app when user installed it first time

Tags: android

i am new in android and stuck in very different situation where

a.> where i have to check that whether the app is installing first time or not if it is first time then save setting from the user
 i have built this successfully using shared preferences but 
**now when i am running it 2nd or 3rd time  the app  doesn't saved the settings set in first run and comes with fresh default values**

for eg .. i have selected and saved the state rajasthan  from spinner but on second run it comes with 1st value in spinner(gujrat) i am using normal variables for this and not intializing with any default value

Comment: if you are using your shared preference well, then the problem will be in Spinner load.. post your code

Comment: i am using shared preference only for checking  whether the app is loaded for first time or not and spinner is perfectly working as i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for save value -

```
boolean flag=false;     //Declare an flag for first time install condition 

private SharedPreferences preferences;  //Declare sharedprefrence for stor local values for app.

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    flag=preferences.getBoolean("KeyFlag", false);
    if(flag)
    {
        // do code  here for next time installed
    }
    else
    { 
        // for first time installed you have to put true value in flag
        Editor editor=preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("KeyFlag", true);
        editor.commit();  //Don't forget to commit the editor

    }

}
```

Hope this code helps you !!!!
if its is not working please let me know i will try to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

From second time u need to compare the selected or saved values with your list(Arraylist or

array) and then take the position of the values and put spinner.setSelection(position). or

when you are save the selected position first time and second time pass the position to the

spinner